# Make js file not accessible through web console

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is most likely a very simple one.

I have created a game in canvas and js. However I stumbled upon a problem. As I can access the variables and code inside the chrome console, I can change f.ex. the player score to whatever I'd like. This is not very good.

Is there some way I can make the file and variables non accessible through the console for players to use?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you explicitly assigning to `window.` properties? (post some of the code?)

Comment: No, every asset you need in your site will be available.  What you can do is minify and uglify (obfuscate) the assets.  Further, any logic related to a transaction should be validated, fulfilled in the backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the whole script into an IIFE so that any variables declared will be scoped to the just-invoked function, rather than be on the top level and accessible anywhere. For example:

```
(function() {
  var playerName = 'bob';
  var turnCount = 1;
  // do stuff with playerName and turnCount,
  // they won't be accessible or changeable from the outside

  // you can declare functions and such here as well
  // which will also only be accessible from the inside

})();
```

Like this, referencing `playerName` from the console will fail.

Comment: That makes alot of sense ^^. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use a proxy.
[javascript proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

or you can make an IIFE and expose only the required functions such as:

```
    var App = (function() {

    var test = '';

    var init = function() {
        App.test = 'test';
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})();
```

or define your properties as not writable with `Object.defineProperty()`